# how to toggle orderby in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show data in ascending and descending on same button click using angularjs .I am able to show data in ascending order .But how I will show descending on same button click (as a toggle in jquery ). I will tell you problem I have button on my table header "V" on that click I sorted column in ascending order .can we do descending order on same button click

when user click first time on colomn first ..**Expected result** is this I am able to achieve this .

```
 Calls   Royal Dutch sell

    p        a royal data

    Xgtyu     test royal dat
```

But if he again click on same button .Then it will show this **Expected result**

```
    Xgtyu     test royal dat

    p        a royal data

   Calls   Royal Dutch sell
```

I need to toggle data from ascending to descending on same button click .

here is my code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/cScyd91eHVGTTGN390ez

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="column in displayData | orderBy: sortval | filter: query">
        <div class="col col-center brd" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="data[$index].checked && data[$index].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
        <div class="col col-10 text-center brd">
        </div>
      </div>
```

**JS code**

```
  $scope.setSort = function(idx){
    $scope.sortval = 'columns['+idx+'].value';
  };
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Notice the syntax of the orderBy filter:

```
{{ orderBy_expression | orderBy : expression : reverse }}
```

Expression is the column to sort by, and reverse can be either true or false. Here is the documentation further explaining this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy.

So change your ng-repeat to

```
ng-repeat="column in displayData | orderBy:sortVal:sortDir"
```

Now in your setSort method add the following code to manage sort direction:

```
 if ($scope.sortVal === 'columns['+idx+'].value')
    $scope.sortDir = !$scope.sortDir;
```

Also define the default sort direction at the top of the controller:

```
$scope.sortDir = false;
```

We initialize it to false, since false is asc sort, and true is desc sort.
Here is an updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fhcmwqWpv8mt23vV69vZ?p=preview